# Exclude specific dates from aging formula

Tags: formula, case

I'm trying to come up with a way to exclude specific dates (holidays) from the following formula:

```
IF( IsClosed, 
CASE(MOD( Opened_Date__c - DATE(1985,6,24),7), 
0 , CASE( MOD(Closed_Date__c - Opened_Date__c,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,5,1), 
1 , CASE( MOD(Closed_Date__c - Opened_Date__c,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,4,6,5,1), 
2 , CASE( MOD(Closed_Date__c - Opened_Date__c,7),1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
3 , CASE( MOD(Closed_Date__c - Opened_Date__c,7),1,2,2,2,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
4 , CASE( MOD(Closed_Date__c - Opened_Date__c,7),1,1,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
5 , CASE( MOD(Closed_Date__c - Opened_Date__c,7),1,0,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,0), 
6 , CASE( MOD(Closed_Date__c - Opened_Date__c,7),1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,5,0), 
999) 
+ 
(FLOOR((Closed_Date__c - Opened_Date__c)/7)*5-1), 

CASE(MOD( Opened_Date__c - DATE(1985,6,24),7), 
0 , CASE( MOD(TODAY() - Opened_Date__c,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,5,1), 
1 , CASE( MOD(TODAY() - Opened_Date__c,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,4,6,5,1), 
2 , CASE( MOD(TODAY() - Opened_Date__c,7),1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
3 , CASE( MOD(TODAY() - Opened_Date__c,7),1,2,2,2,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
4 , CASE( MOD(TODAY() - Opened_Date__c,7),1,1,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
5 , CASE( MOD(TODAY() - Opened_Date__c,7),1,0,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,0), 
6 , CASE( MOD(TODAY() - Opened_Date__c,7),1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,5,0), 
999) 
+ 
(FLOOR((TODAY() - Opened_Date__c)/7)*5-1) 
)
```

There are 8 specific dates per year that I need to include for 5 years out, so 40 dates in total.

Is there a simple way to include these specific dates in the formula so that it will skip them when tallying the count?

Any ideas would be more than welcome, I'd love to do this without code!

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information? Specifically, what is the formula actually designed to do?

Comment: Hi Christopher, the formula needs to track Case Age in Business Days.  So far we have it looking at M-F, but it still doesn't take the 8 holidays per year into account, which is what would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement and i did it with the following formula. It worked for me i hope it will be helpful:

End date and start dates - i am using as date range in which there will be holiday on 1 jan 2016 
 it will exclude weekends as well.

```
CASE(MOD(  start_date__c - DATE(1985,6,24),7), 
0 , CASE( MOD( end_date__c - start_date__c ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,5,1), 
1 , CASE( MOD( end_date__c - start_date__c ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,4,6,5,1), 
2 , CASE( MOD( end_date__c - start_date__c ,7),1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
3 , CASE( MOD( end_date__c - start_date__c ,7),1,2,2,2,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
4 , CASE( MOD( end_date__c - start_date__c ,7),1,1,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
5 , CASE( MOD( end_date__c - start_date__c ,7),1,0,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,0), 
6 , CASE( MOD( end_date__c - start_date__c ,7),1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,5,0), 
999) 
+ 
(FLOOR((  end_date__c - start_date__c )/7)*5)- (IF(AND( end_date__c  >  DATE(2016,01,1),
start_date__c < DATE(2016,01,1),
 CASE(MOD( DATE(2016,01,1) - DATE(1900, 1, 6), 7), 0, "Saturday", 1, "Sunday", 2,"Monday", 3, "Tuesday", 4, "Wednesday", 5, "Thursday", 6,"Friday","") <> "Saturday",
CASE(MOD( DATE(2016,01,1) - DATE(1900, 1, 6), 7), 0, "Saturday", 1, "Sunday", 2,"Monday", 3, "Tuesday", 4, "Wednesday", 5, "Thursday", 6,"Friday","") <>  "Sunday"),1,0))
```

you can create custom setting for holiday list and use the same in formula field.